# Is there a direct function in python to normalise values in a single column of a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Is there a function in any python library by which I can normalize certain columns of a matrix independently? For instance:

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
```

if I want a transformation of the above matrix to

```
1 1 3
1 1 4
1 1 5
```

i.e normalize the values in the 2nd column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by normalize?

Comment: To scale values in a column so that they lie within 0-1.

Comment: @DavidG it was a typo. Ive edited the question. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @DavidG thanks. I am aware of that, however I was wondering if there already exists a function to do that. If not, it would be a nice addition to the existing libraries like numpy etc.

Comment: By what formula vector `[2,2,2]` gets normalized to `[1,1,1]`?

Comment: Division by the max value in the vector.

Comment: That would be `M[:, 1] /= M[:, 1].max()`. Are you sure you need a dedicated function for that?

Comment: what should happen to negative values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

You can use np.linalg.norm

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html